# Charm/intimidate option in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is there any sure shot methodology to get the `charm/intimidate` option to be available in mass effect 3?

For instance,

> in Priority : Tuchanka, i had to lose Mordin Solus because i didnt have a suitable charm/intimidate decision.

And [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Tuchanka), it has been stated that :

> Shepard may also have Charm and Intimidate options available. If so,
>   Mordin agrees to delay the genophage cure until after the Reaper
>   threat has passed, and to become a War Asset at the Crucible project
>   in the meantime

I would like to know what i should do to get these in my decision tree. Thank you.

Comment: I added a spoiler tag to your.. well spoiler.

Comment: @Resorath Good :)

Comment: @Moderators, Kindly dont close this question down. This doesnt deal with this one issue alone. I will have to use charm/intimidate in Priority : Rannoch as well. So i want to know how to make sure i get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can glean from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53843/can-i-cure-the-genophage-without-losing-a-salarian) which actively answers your example, as well as my [own question about Ashley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54992/how-do-i-save-ashley), some dialog options are purely based on your previous interaction with that character - perhaps even as far back as previous Mass Effect games.

There is no sure-fire way of getting those options in a generic sense, although charm/intimidate options for Admiral Koris for example, appear to be based on reputation alone (combined paragon/renegade).