# How to save Ashley

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I save Ashley?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54992/how-do-i-save-ashley)

Thane survived in ME2 and was loyal to me. But he did not show up to interrupt the assassination of the Senator. Does any one know why he didn't come to my aid? As a result, I couldn't convince Ashley and she was shot by my squad member...

Comment: Duplicated post, should be close as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Thane only shows up if you speak to him before the mission. However even if the salarian counciler is dead you can still save Ashley if you have high enough reputation. And don't forget to take the Paragon/Renegade interrupts.